# SQLITE JOIN Issue: How to match same value with different spellings

Tags: python, sqlite, join

I'm trying to join two tables in an sqlite database.

Here is the join statement:

```
join_command = 'SELECT country, year, men_years, women_years, total_years, _1999, _2000, _2001, _2002, _2003, _2004, _2005, _2006, _2007, _2008, _2009, _2010 FROM education LEFT OUTER JOIN gdp ON education.country = gdp.country_name;'

with con:
    cur.execute(join_command)
    data = cur.fetchall()
df_combined = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The join statement works as expected.

I'm joining table "Education" with column "Country" with table "GDP" column "country_name". The problem is that some country names are spelled differently. For example, education has "United States" and gdp has "United States of America."

With the left outer join, it is returning:

```
89  United States of America    2008    15  17  16  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Is there a way either in sqlite or python to identify and map column elements that have the same value but different representations, such as United States vs USA or Tanzania vs the Republic of Tanzania.

Comment: How would such an algorithm know that "Republic of China" and "People's Republic of China" are not the same? This cannot be done automatically.

Comment: sure. I understand that. Nevertheless, this can't be the first time someone has encountered this issue when joining tables. What are some recommended techniques or tools that could help: 1)identify any values from either column that were not able to find a counterpart in the other table 2)and then map them together.

Comment: You could have an additional table with two columns: country and country_name with rows, e.g.: [United States, United States] and [United States, USA]. Then you can do a chain of joins between the three tables.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I ended up figuring out the difference in spelling by using list(set(df2['column1']-set(df1['column2']). Then I just went into the original CSV and changed the spelling. I know this is a bit of a hack, but given my current skill level, this was probably the fastest fix.